# How to retrieve posts from following users at once?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to retrieve the posts from the following users by their IDs. I have reviewed many articles, but I haven't found a solution yet. Maybe, I am not looking at the right place.

Database Structure:

```
 Firestore-root
   |
   --- users (collection)
   |     |
   |     --- uid (documents)
   |          |
   |          --- name: "User Name"
   |          |
   |          --- email: "email@email.com"
   |
   --- following (collection)
   |      |
   |      --- uid (document)
   |           |
   |           --- userFollowing (collection)
   |                 |
   |                 --- uid (documents)
   |                 |
   |                 --- uid (documents)
   |
   --- posts (collection)
         |
         --- uid (documents)
              |
              --- userPosts (collection)
                    |
                    --- postId (documents)
                    |     |
                    |     --- title: "Post Title"
                    |     |
                    |     --- date: September 03, 2018 at 6:16:58 PM UTC+3
                    |
                    --- postId (documents)
                          |
                          --- title: "Post Title"
                          |
                          --- date: September 03, 2018 at 6:16:58 PM UTC+3
```

Function to retrieve posts:

```
static func subscribe(userID: String) -> AppThunkAction {
        AppThunkAction { dispatch, _ in

            let listener = Snapshot<Model.Photo>.listen(.photos(userID: userID), queryBuilderBlock: {
                $0.order(by: .updateTime, descending: true).limit(to: 30)
            }) { result in
                switch result {
                case let .success(photos):
                    dispatch(PhotosAction.updatePhotos(photos: photos))
                case let .failure(error):
                    print(error)
                    // error handling
                    dispatch(PhotosAction.updatePhotos(photos: []))
                }
            }
            dispatch(PhotosAction.updateListener(listener: listener))
        }
    }
```

Comment: how it is related to swiftui ???

Comment: which part exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways that you can achieve that. You will need to get the `uid` per users and compare it with the `uid` from the posts. I would recommend you to take a look at the Community post [Firestore: Queries and Security (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50539113/firestore-queries-and-security-swift). This post provide some ideas on how to achieve that.

Besides that, the official documentation [Querying and filtering data](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries) provides examples of queries with Swift.

These other two below posts should provide you some additional insights on querying with Swift, per ids.

- [Get document id From Firestore Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54628601/get-document-id-from-firestore-swift)
- [Query Firebase Firestore documents by the ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48466028/query-firebase-firestore-documents-by-the-id)

I could find these below two repositories, that have Firestore post applications - not in Swift - that might help you get ideas as well, on how to perform queries and the logic to retrieve posts per user.

- [CloudFirestore-Android](https://github.com/jirawatee/CloudFirestore-Android)
- [photo-blog-app](https://github.com/RajaVamsi11/photo-blog-app)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Not exactly :(. Maybe, I am not good enough to understand. The point that I don't understand. I can get all IDs of users that I follow. But, I don't know how to query posts by these IDs at once. By the abovementioned query in my post, I can only query one user.

Comment: Hi @PeaceCloud There are some documentation on it - as this one [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) and [here](https://medium.com/google-developers/update-and-customize-queries-on-your-cloud-firestore-data-for-actions-on-google-7eb1010b417f) - that you can check and this very good post on the [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721517/google-firestore-how-to-get-document-by-multiple-ids-in-one-round-trip), that provides more insights on it. You should understand better queries of multiple documents.